# XPTable Scrolling makes error

Tags: c#, winforms, xptable

I'm using XPTable for storing values in my winform application. Its working fine and has a lot of features. But i'm facing a problem when scrolling through the table. If the scrolling point is in the middle of the table and i'm importing some data to the table means, suddenly the table shows a weird image like below.

[image: Weird result of table]

Is there anyway to avoid this problem? Is that related to painting? I have searched more on the net regarding this problem, but found nothing. Can anyone using this `xptable` answer me?

Edit: XPtable is related to 32bit but i'm using it in 64bit . is that causing the error? other functions work fine.

What i'm doing is, I'm getting the user's input through a text file and loading those values into the database. After that's done i'm fetching values from the database and importing it to the table as follows. (Because of large data in text file i'm storing the db and retrieving. Otherwise, it causes hang problem or takes too much time)

```
foreach (var tokens in list2)
{
    string uname = tokens.name;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uname))
    {
        uname = "";
    }
    Row r = new Row();
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell(snumber, Color.FromArgb(232, 79, 79), Color.White, f1));
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell(uname, Color.FromArgb(232, 79, 79), Color.White, f1));
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell(tokens.Token, Color.FromArgb(232, 79, 79), Color.White, f1));
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell(tokens.Campaign, Color.FromArgb(232, 79, 79), Color.White, f1));
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
    r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        tableModel1.Rows.Add(r);
    }));
    snumber++;
}
```

If the `scrollbar` is in the starting position, it doesn't make any problem. In that weird image , if i click anywhere it showing the cell value. Its totally weird :(

Comment: Did it return some sort of error? Have you looked in the XPTable documentation about what this means?

Comment: i have searched that but nothing found

Comment: Where did you get the component from? Where did you download it?

Comment: here is link http://sourceforge.net/projects/xptable/ and the tutorial for this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19289/XPTable-NET-ListView-Update

Comment: @basic-stuff, this is hard to resolve, since we don't know what is throwing the error, could you show the code that import data in middle of scroll?

Comment: It's definitely an error that's croaking the control.  Perhaps a cell format that is invalid?  Or an operation that changes data to something that fails type validation?  Look at what's happening as things are loaded and cells are refreshed.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Exactly I thought the same and trying to find out why it throws that error

Comment: @basic_stuff could you set a breakpoint at the foreach and scroll down till it hits, then tell us where the exact error is?(where it breaks)

Comment: Then to find it I would watch the Output window in debugger, looking for any exceptions that are thrown, but that are consumed.  Then, set exception breaks on all of those and correct them.  Likely that one will be your culprit.

Comment: @DonBoitnott but it doesn't throw any error

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg I did the same it reading all the data and writing too but after come to look for GUI this weird image shows up again

Comment: Are you by any chance writing to the control from a background thread? Are you forgetting to observe UI thread discipline?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem with an other third party control. the red cross i came across happens when calls wern't marshalled correctly to the main/UI thread when making use of the control. I can see that your marshalling calls to the control, apparently you're accessing the control from an other thread.